# CakePHP Shell issue with my directory structure

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have structured my Cake files in the following way

```
/cakes
 /2_3
  /app
   /Console
    /Command
     /cake.php
/apps
 /www.website1.com
  /Console
   /HelloShell.php
  /Controllers
  /etc...
 /www.website2.com
  /Console
  /Controllers
  /etc...
```

I am getting an error "Error: Shell class HelloShell could not be found."  I have added "cakes/2_3/app/Console" to my PATH, and I am running cake from inside www.website1.com.

```
Current Paths:
-app: www.website1.com
-working: apps\www.website1.com
-root: apps
-core: cakes\2_3\lib
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The file is in the wrong folder

Compare to [Cake](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/master/lib/Cake/Console), whereas your shell is in:

> /app/Console/HelloShell.php

Cake is expecting:

> /app/Console/Command/HelloShell.php

That's also why it doesn't show up as an available shell when typing simply `Console/cake`.

### Be careful with your paths

Especially if you have multiple applications, it's not that good an idea to play around with paths, better to just run the application-specific cli command:

```
$ cd /apps/www.website1.com
$ Console/cake
Welcome to CakePHP v2.x.x Console
...
```

This is unambiguous, whereas it's quite easy to type `cake` in the wrong dir and wonder why things don't work as expected.